# Bring result of PHP-Script to accepted field in TYPO3 FORM

Tags: php, html, forms, typo3-9.x

So, it's my first question here - i found a lot of hints which all working for itself but im struggling now with the final step to get solved.

Guess it's very specific pointed to TYPO3-CMS V9 and higher.

I can also support with all of the Codes, for the moment i guess this will be better on request.

Task: Create a simple Productorderform for logged-in-users pointing just there specific products form the specific price-lists. -> solved by using PHP-Script working with a CSV-File, grabbing also some functions from TYPO3 itself to get needed parameters.
This PHP creates a DATALIST on runtime for the INPUT-Field producing the needed HTML-Code -> solved and working as expected.

Tricky part.
As TYPO3 offers a CORE-Extension called FORM and the Option to - REPEAT - the fieldset.

Also for TYPO3 there is an extension which allows to put PHP-Code directly to TYPO3 as a Content-Element.

FORM itself allows to put Content-Element to a form.

Working so far, but as described, the field (its value) is not recognized when i fire the send button.
So for some reason i have to predefine the trigger also.

I tried step for step to extend the predefined field in the php with the tags of an empty one, all(?) the surrouding DIV etc. to make FORM recognize this field as a "native" field, just extend in the main tag with ... list="prodlist" ...

Well, as you might see, i'm not a developer or programmer, i might have some skills and experiences to know where and how to go with the level (and timeframe) i have.

So i guess the final step might not be that far, but as we say here, i can't see wood because of trees...

The FORM structure by the way is saved to a YAML-file which might be also manipulated, but as i have seen, it gets the triggers -what- to parse in some way from the FORM created.

Many thanks for hints, ideas an hopefully noone was falling to sleep reading this question... ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Short Update: one step works, grab html and make it hardcoded to the php as long the basic field is kept in the form - not very useful but values from the native will be overwritten by the simulated. Just to figure out what might work..

Comment: Finally... it is ..just .. do identify how i can put an extra entrie to the definition of the textfield which is used to type in the products.

This field needs the extra list="xyz", which ist pointing to the datalist-id id="xyz", so the textfield turns in addition to a self-filtering list based on the values of the datalist.

Can be done, as i understand, by using typoscript, but as ou might now, i habe no idea, how the code has to be....

Comment: SOLVED.
Just edit the YAML with a new line i need. To identify where, i just put a placeholder, search for it and put my line directly below the placeholder:
list: prodlist

Now i have another, related question, will ask separately.